# Multiple joysticks event handling

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I want to make a game which is totally same idea as *"Who pressed the button answers the question"*.

I have 2 joysticks and both are connected to a pc. My application will be Winforms and I will develop it on Visual studio 2012.

I've used SlimDX, Sharpx so far I've found nothing for multiple joysticks. My problem is not mesuring the time until a player presses a button, all I want to know is which joystick / gamepad have pressed a button first.

Could you give me ideas about how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could help?

```
public static Joystick[] GetSticks()
    {
        var sticks = new List<SlimDX.DirectInput.Joystick>();
        foreach (DeviceInstance device in Input.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameController, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly))
        {
            // create the device
            try
            {
                var stick = new SlimDX.DirectInput.Joystick(Input, device.InstanceGuid);
                stick.Acquire();

                foreach (DeviceObjectInstance deviceObject in stick.GetObjects())
                {
                    if ((deviceObject.ObjectType & ObjectDeviceType.Axis) != 0)
                        stick.GetObjectPropertiesById((int)deviceObject.ObjectType).SetRange(-1000, 1000);
                }

                sticks.Add(stick);

                Console.WriteLine(stick.Information.InstanceName);
            }
            catch (DirectInputException)
            {
            }
        }
        return sticks.ToArray();
    }
```

Source: http://www.chiefdelphi.com/forums/showpost.php?s=c50dbec48842d636565cf8ad9dad5914&p=1183912&postcount=2

Comment: I think he already had this information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979935/how-to-capture-the-press-time-of-joystick

Comment: Definitely @Heckel

Comment: @hbaktir If you "already had this information" you should include that in your original question. If this answer does not provide you the information you need, please edit your question to include more details about what you have tried instead of asking for "ideas."